# Table headers are on top of the background of modal message

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm walking around a problem for a long time and I can't find out what is wrong. Here is a print screen.

[Print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akNOv.png)

I want the background around the green content to be all dark and as you can see the table headers are above the dark. How can I solve it? Here are the css:

```
.modalMenu {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 15;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
.modal-success-message-content {
    background-color: rgba(0, 230, 0, 0.9);
    margin: 15% auto;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 70%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Here are the css of the framework Im using for the table:

```
.sticky-table {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 80vh;
    overflow: auto;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 0!important
}
.sticky-table table {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    border-spacing: 0
}
.sticky-table table tr.sticky-row td, .sticky-table table tr.sticky-row th {
    background-color: #fafafa;
    border-top: 0;
    position: relative;
    outline: #ddd solid 1px;
    z-index: 3
}
.sticky-table table td.sticky-cell, .sticky-table table th.sticky-cell {
    background-color: #fafafa;
    outline: #ddd solid 1px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
}
.sticky-table table tr.sticky-row td.sticky-cell, .sticky-table table tr.sticky-row th.sticky-cell {
    z-index: 4
}
```

**html table**

```
<div style="white-space: nowrap; height: 60vh;" class="sticky-table sticky-headers sticky-ltr-cells" id="divTableContainer">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr class="sticky-row">
                <th class="sticky-cell"> </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

**html modal**

```
<div class="modalMenu">
    <div class="modal-success-message-content"> <b>SUCESSO: </b>
    <span id="modalSuccessMessageMsg"></span> </div>
</div>
```

**javascript to the headers**

```
jQuery(document).on('stickyTable', function() {
    $(".sticky-headers").scroll(function() {
        $(this).find("table tr.sticky-row th").css('top', $(this).scrollTop());
        $(this).find("table tr.sticky-row td").css('top', $(this).scrollTop());
    });
    $(".sticky-ltr-cells").scroll(function() {
        $(this).find("table th.sticky-cell").css('left', $(this).scrollLeft());
        $(this).find("table td.sticky-cell").css('left', $(this).scrollLeft());
    });
    $(".sticky-rtl-cells").scroll(function() {
        var maxScroll = $(this).find("table").prop("clientWidth") - $(this).prop("clientWidth");
        $(this).find("table th.sticky-cell").css('right', maxScroll - $(this).scrollLeft());
        $(this).find("table td.sticky-cell").css('right', maxScroll - $(this).scrollLeft());
    });
});
$( document ).ready(function(){
    $( document ).trigger( "stickyTable" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to give a higher z-index to your .modalMenu

```
.modalMenu{
     z-index:99999; // number depends on your site
}
```

Comment: if you look here https://jsfiddle.net/dau0o8ro/3/ the modal is "all dark" so i believe something with z-index is your problem. Maybe somewhere else on your code.

Comment: Im using a jquery to make the headers move as you scroll the table, maybe thats the problem, but if I make z-index of the table headers 0 the headers stop moving as I want

Comment: So the problem is somewhere else, not in the above code. Just do some debugging. Try to change your jquery code.

Comment: Already tried everything I can possibly think it is wrong, can't it be the position? relative/fixed/absolute?

Comment: Maybe, edit your post and put your jquery code and everything else we need to show, so we can help you